# Can we apply 'when' condition in 'stages' of a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a `Jenkinsfile` which will be triggered by GitLab (using Webhooks).
I want to skip the whole `Jenkinsfile`'s execution if a particular condition is not met.

One way to do this is to apply the same condition on each stage

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Stage 1') {
            when {
                expression {
                    //Expression
                }
            }
            //do something
        }

        stage ('Stage 2') {
            when {
                expression {
                    //Expression
                }
            }
            //do something
        }

        stage ('Stage 3') {
            when {
                expression {
                    //Expression
                }
            }
            //do something
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

But this seems weird as I want the same condition to be applied for all the stages.
Can we apply similar condition over `stages` itself ? Like this?

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        when {
            expression {
                //Expression
            }
        }
        stage ('Stage 1') {
            //do something
        }

        stage ('Stage 2') {
            //do something
        }

        stage ('Stage 3') {
            //do something
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: You could define a parent stage that has the condition and include the existing stages as nested stages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can we apply 'when' condition in 'stages' of a Jenkinsfile?" No.

Per [Pipeline Syntax, **when**](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) is only allowed *within* a **stage**.

> The **when** directive allows the Pipeline to determine whether the stage should be executed depending on the given condition. The **when** directive must contain at least one condition. If the **when** directive contains more than one condition, all the child conditions must return true for the stage to execute. This is the same as if the child conditions were nested in an allOf condition (see the examples below). If an anyOf condition is used, note that the condition skips remaining tests as soon as the first "true" condition is found.
>
> More complex conditional structures can be built using the nesting conditions: not, allOf, or anyOf. Nesting conditions may be nested to any arbitrary depth.

Can you simply have a first stage with the expression and fail/abort the pipeline if met?

Comment: "Can you simply have a first stage with the expression and fail/abort the pipeline if met?" - 
How can we do it?